# I can't find the file images after uploading them with php function move_uploaded_file

Tags: php

Could someone please help me understand how to find the location of the file and directory when using this PHP function:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'], "tmp/".$file_name);
```

I'm trying to upload images (`jpg`, `jpeg`, `png`, `gif`), but I can't find the file directory of the images after uploading.

Example output after uploading file is: `/tmp/phpqZRudj`

I can't locate this file.

Comment: It should be `tmp` + the path which you specify in `$file_name`. What is `$file_name`, and have you enabled error reporting?

Comment: Example of $file_name is IMG_20170320_0026.jpg.  How do i enable error reporting?  If I try to locate tmp/ directory, there's many file paths.

Comment: Try to make your own upload directory, so you can check it easily. *Note:* If you use Unix operating system, don't forget to set writable access to your upload directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path of the destination file is relative to the "current working directory", i.e. the directory that the script runs from. The function will return `FALSE` if the file cannot be moved for some reason.

I don't think `"tmp/".$file_name` is going to work because of the pathing. If, for example, your script is running in a directory called `public`, you would set the destination to `"/tmp".$file_name` to put it in a directory under public named tmp. (And make sure the directory exists). Notice the leading `/`. ("slash" directory notation works on both windows and *nix). You would then find the moved file in `public/tmp`.

To display errors you need to set the "display_errors" configuration option On. 
`ini_set("display_errors",1);` will accomplish that.

Comment: that helps somewhat;however, I tried to re-run the function, and my upload failed.  so here is sample code for html and php:

Comment: <html>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploads3.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="6291456" />
    Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: <?php

    $uploaddir = '/uploads';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

    echo "<p>";

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
      echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
    } else {
       echo "Upload failed";
    }

    echo "</p>";
    echo '<pre>';
    echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
    print_r($_FILES);
    print "</pre>";
 
?>

Comment: my screen output is:

Comment: Upload failed

Here is some more debugging info:Array
(
    [userfile] => Array
        (
            [name] => IMG_20170320_0019.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpL1HDS7
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 8631
        )

)

Comment: From the php.ini file (/etc/php.ini) the upload_tmp_dir value = /uploads

Comment: You will have a difficult time making progress unless you turn on "display_errors". The "Upload failed" message is not enough info. When "display_errors" is ON it should give a warning like `Warning: move_uploaded_file(../../` which will give helpful info, like the exact file names.

Comment: i found the location of /tmp on vmware.  thanks for the comments, suggestions, and helps here.